# Как сделать, чтобы часть сайта не перегружалась?

Tags: html

Помогите пожалуйста. Сделал сайтик (точнее пародию на него) в Web Studio 5.0... Выложил на бесплатник, но вот проблема: при вызове/переходе на другую страницу опять все рисунки и текст перегружаются... Опять ждешь, пусть не долго, но все же ждешь... Нельзя сделать так, чтобы та часть, где расположены кнопки навигации (выбора/перехода на конкретную страницу), а также логотип заново не перезагружались, а загружалась только часть с новой информацией, относящейся к конкретной странице? Заранее благодарен, хотя на помощь, если честно, сильно не надеюсь...

Comment: JavaScrit + ajax + your site templates + brain = **PROFIT**

Comment: может быть в настройках браузера включить кэширование?

Answer (score 1):

Я, честно сказать, не знаю, что такое web studio 5.0...Вам поможет технология Ajax. Например можете воспользоваться библиотекой jQuery.

Если хотите совсем просто и быстро, воспользуйтесь фреймами(см. HTML тег FRAMESET)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать iframe. Иногда подходит как замена Ajax.

Comment: Я когда-то давно, когда не мог понять как работает Ajax, так и делал= )

Comment: Немного истории - раньше, то что сейчас называют AJAX, делали именно на фреймах/добавлении скриптов в DOM